# iOS : I can't find subscription plans in App store -> Subscription page in iOS device of Test flight build

Tags: ios, flutter, subscription, flutter-in-app-purchase

iOS subscription plans are not showing in App Store -> Subscription Page Section in iOS real device through test flight build after purchased subscription plan

In my app subscription module has been implemented without backend so verification of receipt has been also implemented at mobile side.

Tried Steps :
I have configured all the steps related to Subscription and my app has been approved on App store as well. So when I tried to install approved build on iOS real device and purchase on subscription plan using real apple Id then redirect to check that subscription plans in App store -> Subscription page then its showing **You do not have any subscription** .

When I am trying to test it using sandbox account then subscription plans are showing in Settings->App Store ->Account but not for test flight build using real apple id

Expectation :
App store -> Subscription page should show all subscription plan with current active plan in test flight build using Real Apple Id.